# Compress Selenium screenshot

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, cucumber

I want to make the screenshot used for reporting in selenium lighter to make the overall report lighter

My current method to take screenshots is this:

```
 try {
            final byte[] screenByte = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.attach(screenByte, "image/png", "Evidencia");
      } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
            System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
      }
```

Which is the best way to compress the screenshot to make it lighter? Use a deflater?